# SQL Select sum of previous month group by date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table in the MySQL Data

```
CREATE TABLE `new_table` (
  `date1` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `organisation` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `proportion` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

INSERT INTO `new_table` (`date1`, `organisation`, `proportion`) VALUES ('7/31/2020', 'Clinical Services', '50');
INSERT INTO `new_table` (`date1`, `organisation`, `proportion`) VALUES ('7/31/2020', 'Data and analytics', '60');
INSERT INTO `new_table` (`date1`, `organisation`, `proportion`) VALUES ('8/31/2020', 'Clinical Services', '12');
INSERT INTO `new_table` (`date1`, `organisation`, `proportion`) VALUES ('8/31/2020', 'Data and analytics', '40');
INSERT INTO `new_table` (`date1`, `organisation`, `proportion`) VALUES ('9/30/2020', 'Clinical Services', '25');
INSERT INTO `new_table` (`date1`, `organisation`, `proportion`) VALUES ('9/30/2020', 'Data and analytics', '20');
```

I want to get the `date1` and the sum of the `proportion` group by `date1` as `opening` and `closing` respectively with the following condition

1. When data exists for the previous month, then `SUM(proportion)` of the previous month as the `opening` for the current month and `SUM(proportion)` of the current month as the `closing`.
2. When data does not exist for the previous month, `SUM(proportion)` is the opening for the current month.

The resultant table should be

| Date | opening | closing |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7/31/2020 | 110 | 110 |
| 8/31/2020 | 110 | 52 |
| 9/20/2020 | 52 | 45 |

I'm using the following query

```
SELECT
    date1 as 'Date',
    CASE
        WHEN (
            SELECT
                SUM(proportion)
            FROM
                new_table
            WHERE
                MONTH(str_to_date(date1, '%m/%d/%Y')) = MONTH(str_to_date(date1, '%m/%d/%Y')) - 1
            GROUP BY date1
            LIMIT 1
        ) > 0
        THEN (
            SELECT
                SUM(proportion)
            FROM new_table
            WHERE
                MONTH(str_to_date(date1, '%m/%d/%Y')) = MONTH(str_to_date(date1, '%m/%d/%Y')) - 1
            GROUP BY date1
            LIMIT 1
        )
        ELSE (
            SELECT
                sum(proportion)
            FROM new_table
            WHERE
                MONTH(str_to_date(date1, '%m/%d/%Y')) = MONTH(str_to_date(date1, '%m/%d/%Y'))
            GROUP BY date1
            LIMIT 1
        )
    END as 'Opening',
    SUM(proportion) as 'Closing'
FROM new_table
GROUP BY date1
```

But it is giving the following output where `Opening` is the same for all the rows.

[image]

Sample: https://paiza.io/projects/Jgbxf3Xxag8fKIb3OuasjA?language=mysql

Comment: Which version of MySQL you are using? And would you please share sample data in text format.

Comment: I have update the question with the sample data and editor.

Comment: @Strawberry if you mean the `date1` column, then actually the data source in use has the VARCHAR column. I do not have access to modify it.

Comment: Why `Closing` for the last date is 45 whereas 24+35=59?

Comment: @Akina the question was edited by someone with the sample data which created the mismatch. I have updated the same data in the question.

Comment: I take values from your fiddle. Nobody could alter it storing the link.

Comment: @AnujTBE While you were checking my db-fiddle link i was working on it. Have you face any difficulties then try again. I have changed the link.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT str_to_date(date1, '%m/%d/%Y') date1, 
       COALESCE(LAG(SUM(proportion)) OVER (ORDER BY str_to_date(date1, '%m/%d/%Y')), 
                SUM(proportion)) opening,
       SUM(proportion) closing
FROM new_table
GROUP BY date1
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f39b5524a41cb059b0cecd4ce8f0ef2f)

If the date within the month may differ then use `LAST_DAY(str_to_date(date1, '%m/%d/%Y'))`.

PS. Two sourse data values are used: taken from the question text and from the fiddle by the link.

Answer (score 0):

I have recreate the situation. You can use Lag()Over() to achieve what you are looking for:

```
select date1,coalesce( lag(sumprop,1)over( order by date1) ,sumprop) Opening,sumprop Closing  from (
select date1,sum(proportion) sumprop from new_table
group by date1)t
```

db-fiddle link:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=PieI81lvNT

For older version of MySQL:

```
select date1,coalesce((select sum(proportion) from new_table NT WHERE NT.DATE1<N.DATE1),sum(proportion)) Opening,
              sum(proportion)  Closing from new_table N
group by date1
```

Comment: Because you haven't considered year boundaries.

Comment: *For older version of MySQL:* Provided fiddle on paiza.io uses 8.0.22.

Comment: @Strawberry What is the problem with the boundaries? Maybe you mean that the date column datatype is varchar and format is incorrect?

Comment: @Strawberry . . . Nothing in the question explicitly mentions year boundaries as being an issue.

Comment: @Strawberry will you please elaborate? I have just tried to solve the problem mentioned in the question. Happy to learn from my mistake.